# How to dynamically insert a menu on CMFCMenuBar?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, mfc, c++17

There are already some menus on CMFCMenuBar, now I want to dynamically add a menu item to CMFCMenuBar and keep the original menu

I used m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(m_pXmlMenu->m_wndMainMenu);
I found that the original menu would be deleted. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your Mainframe's message map to respond to [`ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#oninitmenupopup) you can process the insert of menus every time the user will open a top level menu, assuming you are using a `CFMCMenuBar`.

If you are using menus the old way, you will have to respond to [`ON_WM_INITMENU`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#oninitmenu)